# I need sum of value of two timestamps subtractions from the Array

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops

I have one array of hashes and I need the sum of the values determine by the subtractions of two fields (timestamp).

My Array:

```
[
  #<InAppCall id:  1, caller_user_id: 10, receiver_user_id: 61, call_type: "audio", call_answered: true, answered_at: "2020-07-16 04:24:17", end_at: "2020-07-16 04:24:47", created_at: "2020-07-08 09:58:36", updated_at: "2020-07-31 11:10:27", on_going_updated_at: nil>,
  #<InAppCall id: 36, caller_user_id: 33, receiver_user_id: 61, call_type: "audio", call_answered: true, answered_at: "2020-07-11 10:34:03", end_at: "2020-07-11 10:34:33", created_at: "2020-07-11 10:33:15", updated_at: "2020-07-31 11:13:43", on_going_updated_at: nil>,
  #<InAppCall id: 38, caller_user_id: 35, receiver_user_id: 61, call_type: "audio", call_answered: true, answered_at: "2020-07-11 10:34:03", end_at: "2020-07-11 10:34:33", created_at: "2020-07-11 10:33:15", updated_at: "2020-07-31 11:13:43", on_going_updated_at: nil>
]
```

In the array there are 2 timestamp field `end_at` and `answered_at` so I need to subtract these fields and the answer from that sub.

I need to add. I am using rails 6 and ruby 2.6.5

I apply the following logic but did not work, here b is the array

```
b.reduce{|sum,j| {sum + e.end_at-e.answered_at}
```

Also applied this as well but not worked

```
b.map{|e,j| {j += e.end_at-e.answered_at}
```

Here I need an answer in seconds.

Comment: Those are not hashes, those are objects. It's good that you showed what you've tried, but you should also include the actual return value you expect to get. "I need to add" isn't a clear enough description of your expected final result.

Comment: With your current Ruby version you could use [`sum`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Array.html#method-i-sum): `calls.sum { |call| call.end_at - call.answered_at }`

Comment: Further to @anothermh's comment, you should always show the desired return value (as a Ruby object). Being so close to the question you may think it's obvious, but often, as here, it is not. It's also helpful if you assign a variable to each input in your examples. That way readers can refer to those variables in comments and answers without having to define it (e.g., `arr = [#<InAppCall...]`).